# The right place to call stop() for MessageListeners and temporarily pause a connection's delivery of incoming messages.(JMSCC0012..)?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jms, ibm-mq, mq

As I can see in JMS specification connection.stop() can't be called from onMessage() for asynchronous MessageListener. 
**Could you please advise the right place to call connection.stop() to suspend delivery of incoming messages** and don't get exception: *"JMSCC0012: The method 'stop()' may not be called from a message Listener."* **and automatically resume the connection after some event?** What the best practices of using connection.stop()?

> **From JMS 2.0 spec:**
>
> 6.1.5. Pausing delivery of incoming messages  If any message listeners are running when stop is invoked, stop must wait until all of them
>   have returned before it may return. While these message listeners are
>   completing, they must have the full services of the connection
>   available to them. A message listener must not attempt to stop its own
>   connection as this would lead to deadlock. The JMS provider must
>   detect this and throw a javax.jms.IllegalStateException.
>
> **From jms 1.1:**
>
> 4.3.4 Pausing Delivery of Incoming Messages  If MessageListeners are running when stop is invoked, stop must wait until all of them have
>   returned before it may return. While these MessageListeners are
>   completing, they must have the full services of the connection
>   available to them.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in my case was to setup `volatile boolean`  variable `suspendConnection` from `onMessage()`. And check this variable from other thread which parsing messages. When variable `suspendConnection` was setup inside `onMessage()` I call `connection.stop()` from parser thread.